# Custom sum with groupby pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-analysis

I am trying to make a group by with custom sum.

I have a dataframe with following columns:

**date | describe | time | fees**

I try to groupby with following order:
`df.groupby(['date', 'describe', 'time', 'fees'])['fees'].sum()`

but I want to sum 'fees' based on 'date' column.

Any Idea to solve that?

Comment: `df.groupby(['date'])['fees'].sum()` ?

Comment: the output of sum will be correct, but I will lose the rest columns, so I need to be the final result: 

"date" | "describe" | "time" | "fees" | sum("fees based on date"

Comment: or | "date" | sum(fees of date) | "describe" | "time" | "fees"|